# Flush of BufferedWriter only works when debugging

Tags: java, debugging, flush, bufferedwriter

I'm currently working on a project in java.

I have a method in a server class which sends an input string to a particular socket.

```
    private void inviaSingoloGiocatore(Giocatore giocatore, String outputString) throws DisconnessoGiocatoreCorrenteException {
    long beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = 0;
    boolean freezed = false;
    while (TIMER - elapsedTime > 0){
        try {
            Socket socket = sockets[giocatore.getIndice()];
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            outputString += "\n";
            out.write(outputString);
            out.flush();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(!freezed){
                inviaTuttiGiocatori(encoder.freeze(giocatore)); //Freeze
                freezed = true;
            }
        }
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-beforeTime;
    }
    inviaTuttiGiocatori(encoder.disconnesso(giocatore));//disconnesso
    throw new DisconnessoGiocatoreCorrenteException();
}
```

The problem is that the flush only works when i stopwatch it with the debugging tool and press f6 to execute it. Even if i put the stopwatch on the next line it does no longer work.

I can't figure out this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use try with resources or a try with a finally block whenever you open closeable resources like output streams and sockets. You are not closing your stream at all and you are basically leaking filehandles in a while loop.

so something like this in your while loop will probably work a lot better. The try automatically closes your resource after the block exits. That should also take care of the flush. You should set the character encoding on the OutputStreamWriter. This code will mishandle UTF-8 on some platforms:

```
try(Socket socket = sockets[giocatore.getIndice()]) {
  try(BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF8")))) {
    out.write("whatever it is you wanted to write, outputString was not defined");
  }
}
```